# How to do OR inside of AND?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

SQL query=>

```
where and ((subtype="dailyMessage" and registDate="today") or(subtype !="dailyMessage"))
```

i want to retrive this query by using mongodb.

i have this collection. (today is '2017-08-16T15:48:19.947Z')

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597768443b1fd6308c0350c0"),
    "type" : "message",
    "subtype" : "dailyMessage",
    "message" : test1",
    "registDate" : ISODate("2017-08-16T15:48:19.947Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597768443b1fd6308c0350c1"),
    "type" : "message",
    "subtype" : "dailyPush",
    "message" : test2",
    "registDate" : ISODate("2017-07-25T15:48:19.947Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597768443b1fd6308c0350c2"),
    "type" : "message",
    "subtype" : "dailyPush",
    "message" : test3",
    "registDate" : ISODate("2017-07-24T15:48:19.947Z")
}
```

here is my code(spring boot mongodb , using java 8)

```
    List<String> listOfmessage = new ArrayList<String>();
    listOfSubtype.add("dailyMessage");
    criteria = Criteria.where("test").is("james");    
    criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("registDate").gte(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)).lte(LocalDateTime.now())  , Criteria.where("subtype").in(listOfmessage) .orOperator(Criteria.where("subtype").nin(listOfmessage)));
```

my problem is that how can i insert orOperator on the andOperator?

Comment: Can you show a sample document ?

Comment: i added my sample collection

Comment: your SQL query doesn't seem to make sense.....  you have AND ((condition1 AND condition2) OR (condition3))  Should this not just be (condition1 AND condition2) OR condition3

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the `and` outside the whole condition doesn't make sense. The below code is written for the following condition.

```
(condition1 AND condition2) OR condition3
```

**Code:-**

You may need to alter the below code to get the `MongoOperations` object based on your Spring configuration.

**"register"** is the collection name. You can change it accordingly as per your collection name.

```
public Boolean getRegisterData() {

        MongoOperations mongoOperations = getMongoConnection();

        List<String> listOfSubType = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfSubType.add("dailyMessage");

        List<String> listOfMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfMessage.add("test1"); 

        Criteria criteriaSubTypeAndDate = new Criteria();

        criteriaSubTypeAndDate.andOperator(Criteria.where("registDate")
                .gte(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)).lte(LocalDateTime.now()),
                Criteria.where("subtype").in(listOfSubType));

        Criteria criteriaSubType = Criteria.where("subtype").ne("dailyMessage");

        Criteria criteriaFull = new Criteria();

        criteriaFull.orOperator(criteriaSubTypeAndDate, criteriaSubType);


        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(criteriaFull);

        System.out.println(query);

        mongoOperations.executeQuery(query, "register", new RegistryDocumentCallbackHandler());

        return true;

    }
```

**Result set document processing class:-**

processDocument() method will get executed for each document in the result set.

```
public class RegistryDocumentCallbackHandler implements DocumentCallbackHandler {

    @Override
    public void processDocument(DBObject dbObject) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {
        System.out.println("Registry collections data ===>" + dbObject.toString());

    }

}
```